# BackgroundWorker_DoWork causing UI to be unresponsive?

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, backgroundworker

I am using a backgroundworker to fill a bunch of datasets using tableadapter.fill(). For some reason they are causing the UI to be unresponsive. How is this even possible? I'm not reporting any information back to the UI with it...it's just supposed to run in the background, no progressbar.

```
Me.spOpportunityTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.spOpportunity, CType(ActiveStatus, Integer))
Me.ClientTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.Client)
Me.ClientTypeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.ClientType)
Me.ClientPriorityTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.ClientPriority)
Me.OpportunityStatusTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.OpportunityStatus)
Me.MarketSegmentTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.MarketSegment)
Me.ProcurementTypeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.ProcurementType)
Me.BusDevProjectTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.BusDevProject)
Me.ProjectTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.Project)
Me.StateTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.State)
Me.OrgMapTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.OrgMap)
Me.EmployeeTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.Employee)
Me.ClientServiceManagerViewTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DsBdPipeline.ClientServiceManagerView)
```

Comment: can you show your code so we can figure out the problem?

Comment: BackgroundWorker is so .NET 2.0.  Use the Task Parallels Library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx)

Comment: Ok there is the code in the BackgroundWorker_DoWork method

Comment: @Greg Sansom: It's an older app that I am supporting. I have no choice in technology. And we it's on .NET 2.0...

Comment: For testing, try commenting out everthing within the method and replace it with `Threading.Sleep(10000);`.  This should help isolate the issue.

Comment: @Greg, I don't understand...how will that help me isolate the issue?

Comment: @RichardDesLonde: The GUI might become unresponsive even using background worker if it uses up a lot of the CPU, for example when putting an infinite loop inside it.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde: It's more work for me to tell you how it will isolate the issue than it is for you to perform the test.

Comment: @cubski: Thanks, but the CPU stays at 0% or 1% the whole time.

Comment: @Greg, ok, but I don't even understand what you want me to do...comment out everything in DoWork and just put Threading.Sleep(10000)?

Comment: @RichardDesLonde: can you include your background worker class implementation?

Comment: @cubski: My original post has all the code that is in the backgroundworker_DoWork method. The RunWorkerCompleted method has nothing in it.

Comment: @RichardDesLonde: were you able to try Greg's advice then?

Comment: @cubski: I have no idea what he is suggesting.

Comment: Just replace the code you posted with `Threading.Sleep(10000)` and see if the UI becomes responsive.

Comment: @GregSansom Ok I did it and the UI remained responsive.

Comment: Also, the SP that the tableadapter uses to fill is very fast and comes back in 1 second in SSMS.

Comment: Ok it has something to do with what these table adapters are binding too...

Comment: What's your hardware like? Does your CPU only have 1 core?

Comment: @RichardDesLonde - You have to be right.  Even if the CPU use was high, the UI would still be responsive(ish), even on a single-core CPU, (and even the 'ish' cold be removed by lowering the priority of the BGW).  It's got to be those pesky table adapters and whatever visual components are databound to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly I don't know the why's and wherefores of why this was having trouble for some users and not others, but here is what fixed the problem.

I traced it to the `TableAdapter.Fill` methods executing in the backgroundworker `DoWork` method. It made no sense to me that something executing on a background thread, and which was not updating the UI with it's progress, would cause the UI to be unresponsive. So I figured it must be what the TableAdapter is filling being bound to a UI component and causing problems (only God knows why).

So I took all the design-time databinding off the controls. I reordered things so that in the backgroundworker thread, the `TableAdapter`'s fill. In the `RunWorkerCompleted` method, I bind the controls to the BindingSource.

And voila, problem solved.

Comment: +1 for posting your solution.  Sorry to comment on an old thread like this but I ran into something that might help those searching this.  I had the same problem here and tried the solution posted but after a few seconds the UI would still lock up anyways.  I found that a property of my DataGridView was the causing the UI to lock up even though I knew I had no cross threading issues and that my BackGroundWorker/Task was setup properly.  AutoSizeColumnsMode or AutoSizeRowsMode both will lock up the UI on queries running longer than 3 or 4 seconds.  Dissable or set this to "none" will fix it